# Salvando resultado em arquivo txt

Tags: java, txt

Galera como como eu salvaria a saida do programa para arquivo txt ?
no exemplo eu chamo o cmd e peço que realize algo, queria salva o resultado em um arquivo de texto.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class test {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {



    String line;
    Process saida;

    //executa o processo e armazena a referência em 'Saida'

    saida = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c ipconfig");



    //pega o retorno do processo

    BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new 
            InputStreamReader(saida.getInputStream()));

    //printa o retorno
    while ((line = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);

    }
    stdInput.close();

}
}
```

Comment: http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-write-a-string-to-a-file.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053467/how-do-i-save-a-string-to-a-text-file-using-java

Answer (score 2):

Aqui vai uma maneira bem simples, baseada nos [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#write-java.nio.file.Path-byte:A-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-).

---

> Inclua esses imports:

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;
```

> Crie esse `path`:

```
Path path = Paths.get("/endereco/do/seu/arquivo.txt");
```

> E troque o seu `System.out.println(line);` por:

```
Files.write(path, line.getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
```

> Para criar um arquivo, ao invés de usar um existente, inclua logo após a criação do `path`:

```
try {
    Files.createFile(path);
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println(e);
}
```

Comment: Mano é o seguinte acontece que eu dá forma que vc me indicou funciona , mas ele não criar um arquivo txt , no caso tem de existe um arquivo já e ele vai só sobrescrever em cima dele

Comment: @LucasLuan Editei minha resposta.

Comment: Mano deu certo ele cria o arquivo mesmo não existindo arquivo ele cria, e se eu quizer-se mostrar a leitura do arquivo ? podia colocar um print dentro do while ? ou não ?

Comment: Você está *criando* um arquivo, e não *lendo*, certo? Se você quiser deixar o `println` lá dentro não há problemas. Ler o arquivo são outros quinhentos... :p

Comment: Se a resposta funcionou para você, por favor marque-a como 'aceita'... :)

Comment: ta mano , vlw pela ajuda

Answer (score 1):

Não vou ter tempo de editar o código mas vou te explicar como ele funciona e você pode adaptar para sua necessidade.

Nesse caso criei funções que criam o arquivo txt(que no caso chamo de carteira), e tem também uma função que verifica a existência do mesmo
o que você deve fazer é chamar a função de verificação, e caso não exista você chama a função que ira criar uma.

```js
    public boolean verifCarteira(String carteira) {
        File file = new File(carteira);

        return file.exists();

    }

    public boolean criaCarteira(String Carteira) throws IOException {
        new File(Carteira).createNewFile();
        File file = new File(Carteira);
        return file.exists();
    }
    
    public boolean verifRegistro(String registro) {
        File file = new File(registro + "registro.txt");

        return file.exists();

    }

    public void criaRegistro(String registro) throws IOException {
        new File(registro + "registro.txt").createNewFile();
        File file = new File(registro + "registro.txt");
        if(file.exists()){
            System.err.println("Registro criado");
        }
    }
```